# Does Worklight's direct update only work if update is built with same machine that built executable?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, worklight-appcenter, worklight-server

We have a hybrid Worklight app with iOS and Android environments.  We are finding that the direct update feature only works for our app if the .wlapp update file was generated by the same machine that generated the .apk or .ipa executables.

Is this a known constraint?

We are running Worklight 6.1.0.01 (platform.version=6.1.0.01.20140427-1450).

We are deploying to Worklight App Center.

Comment: Never seen that before? we have build our apk and ipa from many different machines, and not had a problem.  I would verify that the server and worklight versions configs match

Answer (score 0):

The direct update mechanism generates the signature for a given project which is embedded in the web resources at build time. If you build a Worklight application you get a .wlapp file and a native project to build for iOS and Android which results in an IPA/APK. The important thing to note is that the signature in the IPA/APK is the same as the .wlapp file you upload to the Worklight Console.

If the resources between 2 machines aren't exact, the signature inside the newly built IPA/APK will not be the same as the signature in the .wlapp uploaded to the server. This will trigger a direct update.

This may be the cause to the behavior you are seeing and is expected. Leave a comment if this not the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks ... how can I verify that the signature in the .wlapp is the same as the signature in the executable?  What should I looking for?